# Batch file script to register specific dll in a folder not all dll

Tags: batch-file, dll

I have about 5-10 DLL out of 100 which are to be registered during the build and **unregistered after the whole build is completed**, all DLL are in a single folder. For registering I wrote a post build event , but now to unregistered just these 5-10 DLL out of 100 can't seem to get any idea, I am new to batch script so get confused early. I searched some places, but all show how to register/unregistered all files in folder not specific DLL writing a prebuild event to unregister doesn't seem to work in case of rebuild option used to build solution

Comment: `regsvr32 /u file.dll`

Comment: The help file usage seems pretty clear: `Usage: regsvr32 [/u] [/s] [/n] [/i] dllname`.

Comment: that's for single file regsvr32 /u file.dll, I need to unregister 5-10 dll in a single batch script using recursive ,how to give the file name for unregistering recursively

Comment: So brute force it with 10 lines of regsvr32 /u dllname.  Not sure how we are supposed to identify which of the 5 to 10 dll files you need to unregister out of the 100.

Comment: I have the names of the dll which are registered, so any way like creating a txt file containing name and then passing the names in txt file to batch file somehow for unregistering ?

Comment: What is the point for 10 filenames. You can make it easier on you by using the windows clipboard to copy and paste the refsvr32 part.

Comment: @Ajay, you can use a `FOR /F` command to read a text file.

Comment: For now there are 10 file , but in future they may increase, so brute force does not seem good, I will try the comment of @squashman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a way to do it with a text file containing `*.dll` names to `Register` `Unregister`

```
@echo off

::For /f will look for *.dll names in files.txt 
::Than Do register/unregister *.dll as specified in regsvr32
::

for /f %%i in (files.txt) do regsvr32 /u /s C:\Windows\System32\%%i

exit
```

**`For /?`** for help

*usage*

`FOR /F  %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]`

**`RegSvr32` command usage**

```
Usage: regsvr32 [/u] [/s] [/n] [/i[:cmdline]] dllname
/u -    Unregister server
/s -    Silent; display no message boxes
/i -    Call DllInstall passing it an optional [cmdline]; when used with /u calls dll uninstall
/n -    do not call DllRegisterServer; this option must be used with /i
```